# Downloadable Setups for Google Drive Applications

Tags: google-drive

Is there a page from where to download various Google Drive application setups?

I noticed various Google Drive apps allow online installations only. But the problem is at my workplace, there is a restriction from downloading files on numerous PCs. In this case, I could copy the setup and install it later.

Comment: for example Google Cloud Connect