# Google Cloud Connect offline setup not working

Tags: google-drive

I have found [this](http://dl.google.com/dl/appsconnect/googleconnectinstallerenterprise.msi) offline setup for Google Cloud Connect (Google Drive's app), but it doesn't install the plugin actually to the Microsoft Office. Or am I missing to activate something, after installation?

When I start the setup it just goes through a progress bar single time and nothing happens. No alerts for success or error and it gets out of the setup application.

Then I tried to find the plugin in Microsoft Word but the bar was not visible over there. Even I tried to find the entry in Add/Remove Programs but it wasn't there.

PS:-
Few days ago I have asked for Downloadable Setups for Google Drive Applications @
[Downloadable Setups for Google Drive Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/42664/downloadable-setups-for-google-drive-applications)

Comment: Note: Google Cloud Connect is [retiring](http://googleblog.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-second-spring-of-cleaning.html), so this question might not be relevant after April 30th. Do consider downloading and installing the Google Drive application [instead](https://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=3017040).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out accidentally :)

After searching for several hours for why offline setup is not working for me, I decided to give the online setup a try. Just then I came to know that **GCC requires .NET Framework 2.0** as a prerequisite.

As I have just refreshed my own system, the framework 2.0 was absent so.

And the same issue with Google Drive offline setup (.msi) also.

Comment: The offline setups were not displaying any explanation for installation failure (i.e. prerequisite .NET Framework 2.0)